# Webdriver not navigating to passed in URL

Tags: selenium2, selenium-webdriver, java

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Firefox (although the same behaviour occurs in IE and Chrome).

I have been using `driver.navigate().to().("");` and it was working fine for me.

I am passing in other URLs using `driver.navigate().to().("https://www.google.com");`

The browser is loading the previously given URL not the one passed in.

Comment: Did you try to use : driver.get("URL");    ?

Comment: yes i tried not working .

Comment: What error you are getting? Also try to use JAR versino 2.44

Answer (score 2):

There are two alternative methods of performing the task you require;

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");
```

and

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

navigate().to() Navigate().GoToUrl and get() do exactly the same thing so it really comes down to which works for you and fits your coding preferences.